# how to call a modal from another php file when i click my link in my home page

Tags: php, html, css

How to call modal from another php file? Sorry I am just starting to learn wed development.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering this is a bootstrap modal (which it looks like it is), you can create a JavaScript function and echo it out in PHP. Something like this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
 '$("#modal-id").modal("toggle")',
 '</script>';
```

The example above is form the [Bootstrap 4 Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#via-javascript) where it demonstrates calling the modal from javascript. Once that script is echoed from your PHP, it'll run on the page and load the modal.

**To Clarify:** Even if this isn't a bootstrap modal, you can still use the same JavaScript technique to add/remove a class to the modal which you can style to make it show/hide.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to create your modal in a separate Signup.php file then using php include function, include Signup.php inside `Index.php` e.g `<?php include('Signup.php'); ?>`. The php include function is used to call a page inside another page. Dont forget, `index.php` file, thats where you are to to place the link that to call Signup.php